# rename recursively adding parenthere if folder name ending with 4 digits in bash

Tags: bash, rename, recursive-query, parentheses, mv

I have been trying to recursively rename folders whose names ends in four digits.

For example, I have a folder name like this:

`this is the name 2004`

and I'm trying to rename it to:

`this is the name (2004)`

I've tried to split the prefix and digit parts of the name however I cannot `mv` as rename these folder.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
F=$(find . -name '*[0-9]' -type d)

for i in "$F";
do

R2=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $NF}')
R1=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/.\{4\}$//')
R3=$(echo "$R2" | sed -r "s/(^[0-9]+$)/(\1)/g")

mv "$i" "$R1 $R3"
# Even tried:

mv "\"$i"\" "\"$R2 $R3"\"


done
```

Does anyone can review or/and suggest some guidance to allow `mv` to find the initial folder and its destination?

Comment: Are folders to be renamed recursive? Like a structure like: `str 123/str2 456/` has to be renamed to `str (123)/str2 (456)`? You need that `find` option that makes it traverse directories from the most deepest one, it's somewhere in man...

Comment: yes, that the idea indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following command:

```
find -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -type d -exec bash -c 'for dir; do mv "$dir" "${dir%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}(${dir#${dir%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}})"; done' - {} + -prune
```

should work.

- double quote arround variable expansion
- `${dir%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}` to remove last 4 digits suffix
- `${dir#${dir%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}}` to remove previous prefix
- `-exec bash -c '..' - {} +` the `-` to skip the first argument after `-c command` which is taken for `$0`, see `man bash` `/-c`
- `-prune` at the end to prevent to search in sub tree when matched, (suppose `2004/2004` then `mv 2004/2004 "2004/(2004)"` or mv 2004/2004 (2004)/2004' would fail)

Comment: That `bash -c 'for dir'...` looks strange to me. Does it save memory/exeuction speed compared to a single process like `-exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}(${1#${1%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}})"' -- {} \;`?

Comment: it's to avoid to start one batch process for each mv, benchmark should be done to see

Comment: however unlike your comment, it will not rename nested directories

Answer (score 1):

I found Bash annoying when it comes to find and rename files for all the escaping one needs to make. This is a cleaner Ruby solution :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'fileutils'

dirs = Dir.glob('./**/*').select {|x| x =~ / [0-9]*/ }

dirs.sort().reverse().each do |dir| 
    new_name=dir.gsub(/(.*)( )([0-9]{4})/, '\1\2(\3)')
    FileUtils.mv dir,new_name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When `$F` has more than one directoy, the for loop will consider it as a one long entry with newlines (try `echo "F=[$F]"`).
Also use `-depth`, you might have `topdir 2004/subdir 2004`. So first rename the subdir.

When the directories don't have newlines, you can try

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r orgdir; do
   mv "${orgdir}" "$(sed -r "s/([0-9]+$)/(\1)/g" <<< "${orgdir}")"
done < <(find . -depth -name '*[0-9]' -type d)
```